# Does my Ads placement in my App UI follow admob Policy or violates?

Tags: android, admob, policy

Here is the screenshot of my UI.

The page is scrollable if the size of the device is small and only interactable is floating action button.

[image: App]

Please reply if it violates or it is Ok.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a policy question, not programming

Comment: ok sure you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Your app UI does not violates the adMob policy but when you scroll the page make sure that only one ad is visible at a time because adMob clearly states that only one should be visible on screen at a time.

Comment: I just read the Google AdMob policy they said not to place ads between contents and it shouldn't move. Here is the link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

Comment: Yes, u can't place banner ads in between your app content but adMob has Native ad units for that, you can place those ad units between you app content.